# sharepoint folder App permissions - Unauthorized

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, permissions

A python flask application I wrote is using the office 365 library to interact with our company sharepoint (in the 365 cloud).

I setup the below app permissions but
[https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxyyyzzz/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('sites%2Fxxxyyyzzz%2FFreigegebene%2520Dokumente%2FGeneral')/Folders"](https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxyyyzzz/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27sites%2Fxxxyyyzzz%2FFreigegebene%2520Dokumente%2FGeneral%27)/Folders%22)
returns a `401 - Unauthorized error.`

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/>
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="FullControl"/>
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/xyz" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

This resolved to the following permissions:

- Let it have full control of this site collection.
- Let it have full control of this site.
- Let it have full control of the list:

  - Documents
- Let it share its permissions with other users.
- Let it access basic information about the users of this site.

---

Other calls like uploading/downloading files are working but I cant get the list folder/ create folder/ to work.
I also never found any other permissions or higher access levels [in the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint)

What am I missing?

Comment: 401 error means that you not have any access token to do request to sharepoint resource. This error not referred to access rights. First you must fix authentication error, then you will be see what about authorization (access rights) to resource. 403 error referred to access rights.

Comment: To authenticate on sharepoint online you must create AAD app registration with access to sharepoint, and request OAuth token, as mentioned here: https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/azure-python-flask-external-app-consuming-office365-sharepoint-site If you done this, please, provide more information about your project.

Comment: As mentioned other calls are working so it is hard for me to understand why it should be an authentication error. No file is public, but I cann receive them through the api so connection seem to work?

Comment: Browser developer console, Fiddler or another app to debuge web requests can help you to understand difference between sucessful or unsucessful queries of your app. Now I suppose that your app hasn't correct auth token. Unfortunately, you didn't describe how you implemented authentication in your application. Add-in permissions is not authentication. Somewhere in requests in your app missing or incorrect auth token.

Comment: I finally managed to resolve it. The error was very irritating, actually it was a problem creating the folders recursively. The authentication worked using the Office365 python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 401 - Unauthorized error was very irritating, actually it was a problem with creating folder trees.
The authentication worked using the Office365 python library.